# Undo sudo ln -sf

Tags: shell, sudo, ln

I was having an issue pushing a git commit, so I ran `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node` now when running `node -v` or `nodejs -v` terminal tells me `-bash: node: command not found`.

How can I 'undo' the `sudo ln -sf`

Comment: You can't simple undo it, you overwrote your `node` binary. Reinstall `node` using your system's package manager.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: The system's package manager probably wouldn't install `node` in `/usr/local/bin/`. (It's `/usr/bin/node` on my Ubuntu system.) The `sudo ln` command might have clobbered `/usr/local/bin/node`, or there might have been nothing there in the first place. Simon, what does `type -a node` tell you?

Comment: @KeithThompson `-bash: type: node: not found`

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/nodejs` exist? Does `/usr/bin/node` exist?

Comment: @KeithThompson sorry for slow reply, Christmas happened! `Simons-MBP:gourmet_coffee Simon$ type -a node
node is /usr/local/bin/node
node is /usr/local/bin/node` I still have the issue. And yes it does print the two lines of node is /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: No problem on the slow reply, but you didn't actually answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo unlink /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.